# Create function to add commands to custom program

Tags: c#, function, object

I have previous experience in other programming languages but I have decided to try and work with some C#. I have been trying to find a way to create a function that will allow me to create other functions for commands

Example:

```
addCommand("help", public PrintHelp(){ Console.WriteLine("blah blah blah"); });
```

I am just not sure how to create the function so that it accepts another function as a parameter, and then can be called again.

Or I would like to be able to create a object that can save a function something like this:

```
Command Help = new Command;
Help.Function = public void printHelp() { Console.WriteLine("blah blah blah"); };
Help.Command = "help";
```

The second one would be ideal actually. I have tried only the first way by doing something like this:

```
public void AddCommand(string Command, delegate function){
  cmd = Command;
  FUNC = function;
}
```

Comment: Research "delegates" and "lambda expressions"

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# exposes the types `Action<T ... Tn>` and `Func<T ... Tn, TResult>`for passing functions as arguments.

`Action` represents a void method call, while `Func` represents a delegate that returns a type `TResult`. Both classes have overloads that take an arbitrary number of parameters.

In your example, your `addCommand` signature would look like:

```
public void addCommand(string command, Action action);
```

You can then call it using a lambda expression:

```
addComand("help", () => { Console.WriteLine("blah blah blah") } );
```

or by passing in a method group:

```
public void printHelp()
{
  Console.WriteLine( "blah blah blah" );
}

// In calling code:
addCommand("help", printHelp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Function<T,Result>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065950/using-actiont-as-an-argument-in-c-sharp-mimicking-a-function-pointer) for example usage and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for MSDN documentation (the particular MSDN link provides lots of samples).

Essentially with `Action<T>` you can call a method using a lambda expression and hand in the `Action<T>` as an argument to another function (i.e. handing in a function as an argument).  There are standard ways of doing this with C# using the delegate keyword but it is legacy functionality.  If you are looking for the equivalent of a real function pointer then C# doesn't offer that construct directly (it is indirect by means of the delegate keyword).  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is known as the [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern):

> In object-oriented programming, the command pattern is a behavioral design pattern in which an object is used to represent and encapsulate all the information needed to call a method at a later time. This information includes the method name, the object that owns the method and values for the method parameters.

Check out [this simple C# implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern#C.23) and also [this nice tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339390/Understanding-and-Implementing-Command-Pattern-in).